# How to understand quantity in terms of prohibitions and the affect that this has on interacting with that quantity of issur?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, shiurim-measurements, muktzeh

Do all issurim have a shiur and how is that quantified?

An example of what inspired the question. In my taaruvos shiur the rav told us that on yontiff if wood that was muktza such as branches that fell from a tree into your fire it would be necessary to add non muktzah wood to make this botel to continue to benefit from the fire. It's a longer discussion about how one can make an issur botel but that's not what I'm asking about.

Muktza is the rabinic prohibition to move certain types of objects on shabbos (shulchan aruch harav hilchos shabbos section 308 אָסְרוּ חֲכָמִים , לְטַלְטֵל מִקְצָת דְּבָרִים בְּשַׁבָּת כְּדֶרֶךְ שֶׁהוּא עוֹשֶׂה בְּחֹל. "it is forbidden to move muktzah thinng on shabbos in the way way it is done on a weekday:" What is the shiur for moving muktzah? In the case of the fire there was no person who moved the wood but rather it fell in on its own. Since the muktza prohibiton is related to moving the items and these were not moved by the person then why is there a need to make them botel?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking regarding muktzeh. Touching muktzeh is permitted (https://outorah.org/p/4953/). Moving is forbidden. Are you asking if there's a shiur in how far you move it?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the quantity is defined. In the example given the muktzah wood wasn't moved by the person at all it just fell in. I don't understand what needs to be mevatal.

Comment: @mbloch I've edited my question to reflect the quote better since as you have pointed out it's not about touching but moving. I thought handling made sense since it might imply that the item was picked up to move it. like as handling and shipping for mail. either way it's more clear now

Comment: There also seems to be an issue to consume / use / benefit from (certain forms of) muktzeh

Comment: spoke to a friend about this last night and part of the problem with my question is that the understanding of how Muktza applies is different for shabbos and yontiff and as @Joel K pointed out for yontiff there is an issue with benefitting from this type of Muktza on yontiff